# Facebook iFrame app - how to fetch Preload FQL result using PHP SDK?

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-fql, facebook-iframe

since few years I have an FBML app (a small [Flash game](http://apps.facebook.com/video-preferans/)) which I'm now trying to convert to an iFrame app. Unfortunately there aren't many docs for Facebook iFrame apps yet.

For my game I need the user's first name, picture, gender and the city.

In my old version I had this preload FQL (created once by a PHP script):

```
$fql = array('info' => array('pattern' => 'facebook',
    'query' => 'SELECT first_name, sex, pic_big, current_location 
    FROM user WHERE uid={*user*}'));

$fb->api_client->admin_setAppProperties(
    array('preload_fql' => json_encode($fql)));
```

and then my FBML app script had been as simple as:

```
<?php

require_once('facebook.php');

define('FB_API_ID', 'XXX');
define('FB_AUTH_SECRET', 'YYY');

$fb         = new Facebook(FB_API_ID, FB_AUTH_SECRET);
$viewer_id  = $fb->require_login();
$data       = json_decode($fb->fb_params['info'], true);

$first_name = $data[0][0];
$last_name  = $data[0][2];
$female     = ($data[0][3] != 'male');
$avatar     = $data[0][3];
$city       = $data[0][4]['city'];

# and then I'd just construct flashvars attribute
# for the <fb:swf ...> tag and print it

?>
```

Does anybody please have hints on how to recreate the same script for the iFrame version - i.e. **how can I fetch the result of Preload FQL by my iFrame app**?

According to an older Facebook blog entry [Preload FQL should be accessible by the iFrame apps](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/152/).

Thank you!
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My own answer after long searching is that Preload FQL results aren't sent to iframe Facebook apps.

That is why [Facebook performance doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/performance/) says:

"Preload FQL Query and Multiquery.

This section applies to FBML canvas pages, but not to websites or IFrame canvas pages."

Answer (score 0):

As Facebook said for Preload FQL

"*Facebook will send the result of these FQL queries as JSON-encoded POST parameters to your Canvas URL*"

**print_r** your **$_POST** and see which variable is the "*json-encoded results*". You convert json into php object using json_decode

JSON looks like this: `{"var":"val","var":"val"}`

Also, Facebook already has great docs for iframes. Then you might have missed these great docs:

Facebook Docs Home

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Authentication

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Signed Request

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

iFrame Canvas Apps

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/

PHP SDK

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk

Graph API

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: Unfortunately the list of well-known links that you have listed above does not answer my question at all: how to fetch Preload FQL result by an iFrame app. And print_r($_POST) outputs only one string: [signed_request] => xR38Gp9fj...

Comment: Hmmm, maybe it's in signed request! Decode it and print_r everything.

Comment: did you fill-out the preload FQL in ythe advanced settings of your app?

Comment: Yes, I have {"info":{"pattern":"facebook","query":"SELECT first_name, sex, pic_big, current_location FROM user WHERE uid=me()"}} in the "Advanced" -> "Advanced Canvas Features" -> "Preload FQL" field

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call any FQL for the information you are getting. For iFrame you just need to do following steps

1. Download the PHP SDK of graph api https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/
2. Create the object and authorize the app from user

   ```
    $fbconfig['appid' ]  = "your application id";

   $fbconfig['api'   ]  = "your application api key";

   $fbconfig['secret']  = "your application secret key";




   try{
       include_once "facebook.php";
   }
   catch(Exception $o){
       echo '<pre>';
       print_r($o);
       echo '</pre>';
   }
   // Create our Application instance.
   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
     'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
     'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
     'cookie' => true,
   ));
   // User location extended permission allow you to get user's current location
   $loginparams = array('canvas' => 1,'fbconnect' => 0,'req_perms' => 'user_location');

   $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($loginparams);


   // We may or may not have this data based on a $_GET or $_COOKIE based session.
   // If we get a session here, it means we found a correctly signed session using
   // the Application Secret only Facebook and the Application know. We dont know
   // if it is still valid until we make an API call using the session. A session
   // can become invalid if it has already expired (should not be getting the
   // session back in this case) or if the user logged out of Facebook.
   $session = $facebook->getSession();

   $fbme = null;
   // Session based graph API call.
   if ($session) {
     try {
       $uid = $facebook->getUser();
       $fbme = $facebook->api('/me');
     } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
         d($e);
     }
   }

   function d($d){
       echo '<pre>';
       print_r($d);
       echo '</pre>';
   }
   ```

   // You can found all the data in this array.
   print_r($fbme);

For more detail you can follow this tutorial http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Hope it works for you

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, but I'm interested in how to fetch the Preload FQL result. The method you're suggesting already works at my site, but it requires at least one CURL call (when $facebook->api('/me') is called) - and I'd like to avoid that.