# Facebook iFrame app - how to find user's current city?

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-graph-api, location, facebook-iframe

I'm trying to migrate [an old FBML app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894992/facebook-iframe-app-how-to-fetch-preload-fql-result) to iFrame using the new PHP SDK and GRAPH API, but cannot figure out - how to find the visitor's city.

For example in my own Facebook profile I list both **Current City** and **Hometown**:

[image]

But when I try the following iFrame app, the **location** and **hometown** are not printed, while other data including my employers and education is printed:

```
<?php

include_once 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId'  => "182820975103876",
            'secret' => "XXXXXXX",
            'cookie' => true,
            ));

$session = $facebook->getSession();

if (!$session) {
    $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    print("<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$url';</script>");

} else {
    try {
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');

        print('<pre>');
        print_r($me);
        print('</pre>');

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        print("Error:" . $e);
    }
}

?>
```

Here is part of the data I see for myself, the current location isn't there:

```
Array
(
    [first_name] => Alexander
    [education] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [school] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 106509962720287
                            [name] => Riga Nr. 40
                        )

                    [type] => High School
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [school] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 103130426393616
                            [name] => RWTH Aachen University
                        )

                    [year] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 143018465715205
                            [name] => 2000
                        )

                    [type] => College
                )

        )
    [gender] => male
...........
)
```

Regards
Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need the `user_location` and `user_hometown` [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/).

So your login url should read something like:

```
$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'user_location,user_hometown'
));
```

Answer (score 2):

thats not too hard here is what you are getting when you call fb api ( part of a code from examples in FB docs)

`"id": "220439",
   "name": "Bret Taylor",
   "first_name": "Bret",
   "last_name": "Taylor",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/btaylor",
   "username": "btaylor",
   "hometown": {
      "id": "108363292521622",
      "name": "Oakland, California"
   },
   "location": {
      "id": "109650795719651",
      "name": "Los Gatos, California"
   },`

to get that info you call api first
`$me = $facebook->api('/me');`

as you see in the example that the name of a hometown is inside an "hometown" array. same goes for location (current city) its inside "location" array.. so what you do now is

`$hometown = $me['hometown']['name'];
$current_city = $me['location']['name'];`

echo 'You are currently living in: '.$current_city.' but your hometown is: '.$hometown

hope it helps man ;)

EDIT:

```
            $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
            $req_id = $_GET['request_ids'];
            $req = $facebook->api('/me/?access_token='.$access_token);
            echo $req['hometown']['name'];
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't help, because you suggest exactly what I have written in my question already and the hometown and location aren't there

Comment: well the current city isn't there because you probably have no access to get that... are you using access_token ?

Comment: read my answer again at the end i added my personal code which is changed to meet your needs... you wont get hometown unless you use access_token... Ignore the $req_id = I forgot to remove it ;)